# excel Cell increment self by value of other cell

Tags: excel, calculation

I have NEVER used excel before but I wanted to make a small program thingy to easier keep track of levels and experience for some players in my dnd campaign

Now i want there to be a field that displays their current total (A1 for example) and a different field where they input the experience they got during the session (B1 for example) and when they input a new value into B1, A1 updates and increases automatically by the amount in B1 but this seems to oppose the way that excel works as it creates a self reference which it doesn't like.

I do not seem to be able to find an answer to this question at all when I search online (I can't watch videos atm) so if there is somewhere I can find this info that would be much appreciated.

I have tried multiple things:
first try

- A1: =A1+B1
- B1: 10
- result: A1 ended with a value of 0

second try

- A1: =A2
- B1: 20
- A2: =A1+B1
- result: both A1 and A2 stayed as 0 no matter what number i changed B1 to

Comment: Could you not list the experience gained in column A, i.e. 1st session into A2, 2nd into A3 etc and then in B2 go with =sum(A:A)

Comment: That is a circular reference. Formula are not the way to do that. You will want vba.

Comment: @MattDrake i want to make it as easy to use with as little amount of scrolling as necessary and easely visible since one of our players tends to have some trouble grasping new concepts, and especially for the fact that in said case there would have to be 2 columns, besides leveling up there is another leveling bar seperate that our dm has created for a homebrew thing.
i'll keep that as a backup idea incase what im asking for is impossible though